# mapply vs loop in R package

Tags: r, loops, r-package, mapply

I've written a simple function that converts old Japanese text to modern form. I want to post as a package, but I'm trying to improve it in two ways. First, there is a small speed gain using mapply rather than a loop, but I can't get the results I want. Here's the working loop.

```
normalize <- function(doc)
{
  kanji_conversion <- data.frame("old" =c("學","勲"), "new" =c("学","勳"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for (i in 1:nrow(kanji_conversion))
 {doc <- gsub(kanji_conversion$old[i], kanji_conversion$new[i], doc)
  }
  return(doc)
}
```

Works great, and it's at https://github.com/histmr/Rekishi

BUT my attempt at an mapply version returns not a single string but a vector matching the nrow() of kanji_conversion, with one change in each element

```
doc <- "學"
kanji_conversion <- data.frame("old" =c("學","勲"), "new" =c("学","勳"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mapply(gsub, kanji_conversion$old, kanji_conversion$new, doc)
library(stringr)
mapply(str_replace_all, kanji_conversion$old, kanji_conversion$new, doc)
```

Is there a way to use mapply to iteratively overwrite a single version of the object doc, as in the loop?

Second, in a real version of the function, the kanji_conversion dataframe will be 2416 x 2. Should I just include that larger df in the function like the example 2 x 2 df? Or should it be an external file? Is there a "best practice" threshold for file size?

Comment: In the loop, you are assigning `doc` so that it gets updated with the latest `gsub` output, while in `mapply` it is not happening that way.  I think for this kind of operations, the `for` loop is better

Comment: Thanks. Any thought on the kanji_conversion vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long lines will be something you have to explain to CRAN on submission so it's better to have them be hard-wrapped. Also, you don't need to build the data frame in the function if you're making a package. That's a needless bit of overhead. Penultimately, `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed()` is vectorized over `pattern` and `replacement` parameters, so you get a C++-backed super-fast, encoding-friendly helper for what you're trying to do. Finally, `normalize_kanji()` is likely a much better name for the function to avoid naming collisions.

Also, you're going to get other CRAN check warnings, specifically:

> Portable packages must use only ASCII characters in their R code, except perhaps in comments. Use `\uxxxx` escapes for other characters.

You'll either need to negotiate with CRAN on that, convert them to unicode escape sequences or store the data frame as an R data file.

You'll find all ^^ (apart from the fix for that CRAN check warning ;-) in https://github.com/histmr/Rekishi/pull/1 since the translation table is too large to put here.

Your former `normalize()` function is now:

```
normalize_kanji <- function(doc) {
  stri_replace_all_fixed(
    doc,
    kanji_conversion_table$old,
    kanji_conversion_table$new,
    vectorize_all = FALSE
  )
}
```

and

```
normalize_kanji("亞啞惡蘆鰺壓菴桉")
```

returns

```
## [1] "亜唖悪芦鯵圧庵案"
```

This isn't the best possible measure of speed (a more diverse input sampling wld be better, but here's how fast that particular conversion is:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ƒ = normalize_kanji("亞啞惡蘆鰺壓菴桉"))
## Unit: microseconds
##  expr     min     lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
##     ƒ 188.362 190.61 202.7352 193.7235 201.9745 448.688   100
```

in case you wanted to compare with your method.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I was avoiding stringi to avoid dependency issues, but Hadley's code is so solid I suppose that's not necessary. If I understand your changes, I can just build the dataframe in a separate .R file and it will be created when the package in loaded with library()? Is that right? This is my first package so I'm at the edge of my skills and I'm bracing myself for CRAN comments!

Comment: Aye. My PR does that but still tossed the "portability" warnings. Hadley wrote `stringr` which is a wrapper for `stringi`. This only has `stringi` as a dependency. That is a pretty hefty one on Linux systems, but not so much on Windows and macOS where there's a binary installation for them (Debian folks can `apt-get` binary versions as well). `stringi` has tons of helpful and speedy things if you're going to be adding more text processing to this package. Feel free to @ me in one of your GitHub issues if you need pointers on anything. The first pkg is the hardest :-)

Comment: Will do! BTW what's a PR?

Comment: Ah, a "pull request'. I forked your package, made code changes and filed a pull request. You can review the changes and incorporate them into your project with one click.

Comment: Done! GitHub is finally starting to make sense. One final (maybe) question. If I create an R data file, would I load it at the start of the .R file with data()  as with data(mtcars)?